# Encountering unexpected behavior when List rotates with SwiftUI

Tags: iphone, swiftui, ios13, swiftui-list, ios-navigationview

I have setup a relatively basic List embedded in a NavigationView, but when I perform a rotation, things do not work as expected.

**The following screenshots show the sequence of events.**

> When the view is initially presented on an **iPhone** (running iOS 13.1 **17A844**)

[image]

> When the view is rotated from portrait to landscape

[image]

My main interest here is that the back button disappears.

> Finally, when it is rotated back to portrait

[image]

Notice that the `Bar Title` has shrunk and is now aligned with the back button.

This is a simplified version of the code I am using to generate these screens:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: ViewB()) {
                    Text("ViewB")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
                       maxHeight: .infinity,
                       alignment: .center)
                Divider()
                NavigationLink(destination: ViewB()) {
                    Text("ViewB")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
                       maxHeight: .infinity,
                       alignment: .center)
            }
            .padding(.all, 10)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Main blah"))

        }
    }
}

struct ViewB : View {
    private let items = ["A", "B", "C"]

    var body: some View {
        List () { [items] in
            ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(detail:
                    Detail(title: items[index]))) {
                    Text("Blah blah")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Bar Title"))
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to have the UI retain the same appearance after a rotation.

For comparison, when I run this on a physical iPad using **iOS 13.1 (17A844)**, it behaves as expected.

Comment: Two thoughts, but no answer. First, are we talking **iOS* or **iPadOS** 13.1? Either way? It's still beta - and trust me, it may be buggy. Second, and related to the first thought, are we talking about a `List` on an iPad or an iPhone? Here, at least most `List` views I've seen, iPads automatically turn your master-detail list - I've found defined by it being inside a `NavigationView` - into a split screen. AND... in portrait you don't (at least by default) see the master view.

Comment: @dfd This is running on an iPhone, I have updated the question to include this information. Will test on an iPad in a day or so once I can have an iPad OS 13 available.

Comment: One last clarification? iOS 13.1, or 13.0? I'm asking because 13.1 is still in beta, and if that's the version... AHA, never mind. While I noticed this morning that they removed several betas, I didn't try looking on my devices. FYI? iPadOS 13.1 **is** available.

Comment: @dfd I have tested now on a physical iPhone running the latest public release of iOS (13.1 17A844) and it performs as described in the bug. Testing on a physical iPad with iPad OS 13.1, it behaves as expected.